# Ajax search function with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a search form submitted using AJAX. The form and results work well, however I am having issues with the pagination.

The pagination is pulled in from the search results, so when I click the link, I am directed to the search results page, which has no styling.

I am looking to disable the default behaviour of the pagination. My code is below:

```
function doTheSearch () {
         var options = {
            target: '#results',
            beforeSubmit:  showRequest
        };
        $('#filter').ajaxForm(options);
};

    function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
        $('#results').prepend('<p class="searching">Searching database</p>');
        return true;
    }

    $(".pagination a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        doTheSearch();
    });
```

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks
Ben

-------------- EDIT ----------------

The section below is where the current results are displayed:

```
<section id="results">
   <!-- items are displayed here (using ExpressionEngine) -->
</section>
```

I also have a search form which performs the search:

```
<form method="post" action="account/search-results" id="filter">

  <p>
     <label for="keywords">Enter number</label>
         <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" />
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
  </p>

</form>
```

I then have a the template search-results which is pulling the search results into the id="results" above.

Answer (score 0):

If you describe an onclick event of an `<a>` Tag, you have to block the default return. Try it

```
$(".pagination a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    doTheSearch();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: ah I see, the problem I'm having now is as soon as i add the function doTheSearch () { around my var options, the search form breaks altogether. Yet there are no errors in the console. If I remove the function doTheSearch () { my search form works, but the pagination doesn't :(...

Comment: Hi Lorado, I have edited my post above for you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Ben! I still can't realize what you want to have... xD You can place your really FULL code at jsfiddle BUT! Let me tell you about, how you JS is working. May be you've misunderstood how it works... the function doTheSearch() binds the behavior of the form. In other words this function define, what should happens, when the form is submitted. It means, when you click your `<a>` tag, it binds this behavior to the form every time. Theoretically you can change the logic-> by clicking on the `<a>` it'll send some parameter through ajax... Contact me in skype: lorado91 ;)